# How to convert dataframe with YearMonth column to times series in R

Tags: r, zoo

I have the below dataset which is a dataframe. But I would like to convert it into time series so that I can do ARIMA forecasting.
Have searched various topics in SO but could not find anything similar which is at YEARMONTH grain. Everyone talked about date field. But here I don't have date.
I am using the below code but this gives error

```
dataset <- data.frame(year =c(2017), YearMonth = c(201701,201702,201703,201704), sales = c(100,200,300,400))
library(zoo)
newdataset <- as.ts(read.zoo(dataset, FUN = as.yearmon))

# Error:
# 
#  In zoo(coredata(x), tt) :
#  some methods for “zoo” objects do not work if the index entries in ‘order.by’ are not unique
```

I know it gives error because I have year column as 1st column which does not have unique values but not really sure how to fix it.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Regards,
Akash

Comment: Are there no missing or duplicated `YearMonth` in your actual data? Because if there isn't, `newdataset <- ts(dataset$sales, start = c(2017,1))` solves your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to convert `YearMonth` to 1st date of a month and generate `ts`.

```
library(zoo)
dataset$YearMonth = as.Date(as.yearmon(as.character(dataset$YearMonth),"%Y%m"), frac = 0)
dataset
#   year  YearMonth sales
# 1 2017 2017-01-01   100
# 2 2017 2017-02-01   200
# 3 2017 2017-03-01   300
# 4 2017 2017-04-01   400
```

Just for `ts` another option is as:

```
dataset$YearMonth = as.yearmon(as.character(dataset$YearMonth),"%Y%m")

as.ts(dataset[-1])
# Time Series:
#   Start = 1 
# End = 4 
# Frequency = 1 
# YearMonth sales
# 1  2017.000   100
# 2  2017.083   200
# 3  2017.167   300
# 4  2017.250   400
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply...Considering I have data for 10 years, is it recommended to convert yearmonth to date and then use it  ? Is there any better way of doing it ? How do I generate ts for the given dataset as it still gives error of order.by column?

Comment: @Akash If your data got single entry for every month then all you are doing is considering 1st day of month. If you just want to stick to `month numbers` then converting to just a month number(say `1-120` for 10 years can be another option). BTW I hope you are not looking to generate `ts` for every day from your data.

Comment: ok. that makes sense. I have data at monthly grain. So I do not want to generate ts for everyday.

Comment: @Akash I have edited my answer to demonstrate how you use `as.ts` on your data using `yearmon`. Have a look.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Really appreciate. I actually need data similar to data(AirPassengers)  which can help me plot and predict using ARIMA forecasting. And for that I have input as the data I have provided in the dataframe.

Comment: With this I am getting 1,2,3... series in the X axis when I plot ts. However, I would like to show Yearmonth column.

Comment: @Akash You can convert `YearMonth` column back to `character` and add custom label at axis.